# Jquery click event triggered twice in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, vuejs2, onclick

I have a button in ajax mode datatable. A click event is attached  with 
  the button which further sends ajax to change the record. After that i have reloaded the table using

```
 this.table.ajax.reload();
```

The function is working fine also the table is perfectly updated the record but the click function triggered twice and sends ajax twice to update data.

```
     $('body').on('click', '.status-change', function(e) {
        this.changeStatus(e.target.dataset.itemStatus,e.target.dataset.itemId);
      });
```

if i attach unbind with body like:

```
$('body').unbind('click').on('click', '.status-change', function(e) {
        this.changeStatus(e.target.dataset.itemStatus,e.target.dataset.itemId);
});
```

Now the click event is triggering once. But there is no change in table. 
Table sends ajax to reload new Data. but table is not getting update.

Comment: Make sure and check that you have not accidentally included your script twice in your HTML page.

Comment: I am using vue.js component

Comment: @Neha: Take a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45613692/click-triggered-twice-vue-js

Comment: @dLcreations Thanks .stop is same as event.stopPropagation();  already tried not working for me.

Comment: Does `$("#table").DataTable().draw();` redraw it correctly after the event is triggered but not changing the table?

Comment: @CodyＧ after redraw table still not updated. if i remove unbind from click event, table starts updating.

Comment: Why not do `$('body .status-change').off('mynamespace.click').on('mynamespace.click',function(e){...});`